# I'm trying to make my discord.py bot create and add a role to a user however I keep on getting AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, discord, discord.py

Here is the snippet of code that I'm having difficulty with:

The Error I'm getting is AttributeError: module 'discord.member' has no attribute 'add_roles'

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    guild = message.guild
    Member = discord.member
    author_id = message.author.id
    author = str(message.author)
    content = str(message.content)
    channel = message.channel
    print(author_id)
    if content != '':
        print(author + " sent '" + content + "' in " + str(channel))
    await client.process_commands(message)

    if content == 'give admin':
        role = await guild.create_role(name="Gamer", permissions=Permissions.all())
        await Member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: Are you trying to give the role to the author of the message? `await message.author.add_roles(role)`

Comment: `discord.member` is a module, not a class nor an instance. You should know those differences if you're using `discord.py`.